# summary report required from csv attendance data

Tags: powershell

this is my csv file i want to count total days from the 1st of month till the last updated date record, secondly i need employee present days
as per the attendance entries of each employee the csv data content is mentioned below while my expected output is also provided

```
Date    Person  Start   End Elapsed     LateBy          EarlyBy
4/1/2023    abcd    4/20/2023 7:41  4/20/2023 13:30 05h, 49m, 08s   0 hours, 18 minutes, 36 seconds     0 hours, 18 minutes, 36 seconds 
4/3/2023    Aliza   4/20/2023 7:41  4/20/2023 13:30 05h, 49m, 08s   0 hours, 18 minutes, 36 seconds         0 hours, 18 minutes, 36 seconds
4/5/2023    Aliza   4/20/2023 7:44  4/20/2023 13:35 05h, 51m, 35s   0 hours, 8 minutes, 6 seconds       0 hours, 18 minutes, 36 seconds
4/6/2023    Aliza   4/20/2023 7:43  4/20/2023 13:31 05h, 47m, 45s   0 hours, 5 minutes, 3 seconds
4/7/2023    Aliza   4/20/2023 7:43  4/20/2023 13:30 05h, 46m, 10s
4/3/2023    Ambreen     4/20/2023 7:46  4/20/2023 13:41 05h, 54m, 52s
4/5/2023    Ambreen     4/20/2023 7:44  4/20/2023 13:34 05h, 50m, 37s                   0 hours, 18 minutes, 36 seconds
4/6/2023    Ambreen     4/20/2023 7:46  4/20/2023 13:40 05h, 54m, 25s                   0 hours, 18 minutes, 36 seconds
4/7/2023    Ambreen     4/20/2023 7:45  4/20/2023 13:35 05h, 49m, 54s                   0 hours, 18 minutes, 36 seconds
4/11/2023   Ambreen     4/20/2023 7:46  4/20/2023 13:34 05h, 47m, 39s
4/14/2023   Ambreen     4/20/2023 7:48  4/20/2023 13:33 05h, 45m, 00s
```

Output result which i want is like this

```
Date    Person  Start   End Elapsed     LateBy          EarlyBy
4/1/2023    abcd    4/20/2023 7:41  4/20/2023 13:30 05h, 49m, 08s   0 hours, 18 minutes, 36 seconds     0 hours, 18 minutes, 36 seconds 
Total Days  PresentDays WeekEnds    EmployeePresentDays LateCount   AbsentAgainstLateCount  Presentdays EarlyCount  AbsentAgainstearlyCount 
14      1       4       5           1       -           5       1       -   
4/3/2023    Aliza   4/20/2023 7:41  4/20/2023 13:30 05h, 49m, 08s   0 hours, 18 minutes, 36 seconds         0 hours, 18 minutes, 36 seconds
4/5/2023    Aliza   4/20/2023 7:44  4/20/2023 13:35 05h, 51m, 35s   0 hours, 8 minutes, 6 seconds       0 hours, 18 minutes, 36 seconds
4/6/2023    Aliza   4/20/2023 7:43  4/20/2023 13:31 05h, 47m, 45s   0 hours, 5 minutes, 3 seconds
4/14/2023   Aliza   4/20/2023 7:43  4/20/2023 13:30 05h, 46m, 10s
Total Days  PresentDays WeekEnds    EmployeePresentDays LateCount   AbsentAgainstLateCount  Presentdays EarlyCount  AbsentAgainstearlyCount 
14      4       4       8           3       1           7       2       -
4/3/2023    Ambreen     4/20/2023 7:46  4/20/2023 13:41 05h, 54m, 52s                   
4/5/2023    Ambreen     4/20/2023 7:44  4/20/2023 13:34 05h, 50m, 37s                   0 hours, 18 minutes, 36 seconds
4/6/2023    Ambreen     4/20/2023 7:46  4/20/2023 13:40 05h, 54m, 25s                   0 hours, 18 minutes, 36 seconds
4/7/2023    Ambreen     4/20/2023 7:45  4/20/2023 13:35 05h, 49m, 54s                   0 hours, 18 minutes, 36 seconds
4/11/2023   Ambreen     4/20/2023 7:46  4/20/2023 13:34 05h, 47m, 39s
4/14/2023   Ambreen     4/20/2023 7:48  4/20/2023 13:33 05h, 45m, 00s
Total Days  PresentDays WeekEnds    EmployeePresentDays LateCount   AbsentAgainstLateCount  Presentdays EarlyCount  AbsentAgainstearlyCount
```

My powershell code is

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\NOC\Documents\kith\complete1.csv"

# Convert the dates to the appropriate format
$csv = $csv | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Date = Get-Date $_.Date -Format "M/d/yyyy"
    $_.Start = Get-Date $_.Start -Format "M/d/yyyy h:mm tt"
    $_.End = Get-Date $_.End -Format "M/d/yyyy h:mm tt"
    $_
}

# Determine the total number of days between the 1st of the month and the last updated record
$lastUpdatedDate = ($csv | Sort-Object Date)[-1].Date
$firstOfMonth = Get-Date $lastUpdatedDate.AddDays(-($lastUpdatedDate.Day - 1)) -Format "M/d/yyyy"
$totalDays = ($lastUpdatedDate - $firstOfMonth).Days + 1

# Group the data by person
$grouped = $csv | Group-Object Person

# Calculate attendance statistics for each person
$stats = $grouped | ForEach-Object {
    $person = $_.Name
    $data = $_.Group
    $presentDays = ($data | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count)
    $weekends = ($data | Where-Object { $_.Start.DayOfWeek -eq "Saturday" -or $_.Start.DayOfWeek -eq "Sunday" } | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count)
    $employeePresentDays = $presentDays - $weekends
    $lateCount = ($data | Where-Object { $_.LateBy -ne "" } | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count)
    $earlyCount = ($data | Where-Object { $_.EarlyBy -ne "" } | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count)
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Person = $person
        TotalDays = $totalDays
        PresentDays = $presentDays
        WeekEnds = $weekends
        EmployeePresentDays = $employeePresentDays
        LateCount = $lateCount
        AbsentAgainstLateCount = "-"
        PresentDays2 = $employeePresentDays
        EarlyCount = $earlyCount
        AbsentAgainstLateCount2 = "-"
    }
}


# Combine the attendance statistics with the original data
$output = $csv | Select-Object Date, Person, Start, End, Elapsed, LateBy, EarlyBy
$output = $output | ForEach-Object {
    $date = $_.Date
    $person = $_.Person
    $statsRow = $stats | Where-Object { $_.Person -eq $person }
    if ($statsRow) {
        $_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Total Days" -NotePropertyValue $statsRow.TotalDays
        $_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "PresentDays" -NotePropertyValue $statsRow.PresentDays
        $_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "WeekEnds" -NotePropertyValue $statsRow.WeekEnds
        $_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "EmployeePresentDays" -NotePropertyValue $statsRow.EmployeePresentDays
        $_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "LateCount" -NotePropertyValue $statsRow.LateCount
        $_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "AbsentAgainstLateCount" -NotePropertyValue $statsRow.AbsentAgainstLateCount
        $_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Presentdays" -NotePropertyValue $statsRow.PresentDays2
        $_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "EarlyCount" -NotePropertyValue $statsRow

        $_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "AbsentAgainstLateCount2" -NotePropertyValue $statsRow.AbsentAgainstLateCount2
        $_
            }


$output | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\NOC\Documents\kith\complete12.csv" -NoTypeInformation

$stats


-NotePropertyName "AbsentAgainstLateCount2" -NotePropertyValue $statsRow.AbsentAgainstLateCount2
} else {
$_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Total Days" -NotePropertyValue $totalDays
$_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "PresentDays" -NotePropertyValue 0
$_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "WeekEnds" -NotePropertyValue 0
$_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "EmployeePresentDays" -NotePropertyValue 0
$_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "LateCount" -NotePropertyValue 0
$_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "AbsentAgainstLateCount" -NotePropertyValue "-"
$_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Presentdays" -NotePropertyValue 0
$_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "EarlyCount" -NotePropertyValue 0
$_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "AbsentAgainstLateCount2" -NotePropertyValue "-"
}


$stats | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\NOC\Documents\kith\complete12.csv" -NoTypeInformation


$stats | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Getting this output

```
Person  TotalDays   PresentDays WeekEnds    EmployeePresentDays LateCount   AbsentAgainstLateCount  PresentDays2    EarlyCount  AgainstLateCnt2
Aliza               8       0       8           8           -       8       8       -
Ambreen             6       0       6           0           -       6       6       -
Amna                7       0       7           0           -       7       7       -
Arif                4       0       4           3           -       4       4       -
```

i assume total days column values are from the 1st of every month till  updated record of attendance entry(like output desired results i mention earlier in my question) but total days column showing blank, weekends has no values also i want an absent to be mark  against 3 lates

Comment: anyone please help

Comment: stackoverflow is not a free code writing service

Comment: @jamesZ sir i am new in coding but i tried to get helped with google and found some scripts, i have updated my code in my question which tried but it is not completely fulfill my needs

Comment: anyhelp please...

Comment: So, what happens with your current script? You need to explain the problem you have and / or include what result you get

Comment: @james Z thank you for your reply i have updated output results in question also mentioned the issue which i am facing